# v:link:typolink with aditionalParams to set language via flux.field.select

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typolink

I try to create a Content Element to create links to other languages. I think this is possible with just a content element and I do not need a own view helper for this.

What I have so far:

```
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

    <f:layout name="Content" />

    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="landingpage-language" label="Landingpage Language" options="{icon: 'Icons/Content/Example.gif', group: 'My Ele'}">
            <flux:field.input name="title" label="Title"/>
        </flux:form>
        <flux:form.section name="languages" label="Languages">
            <flux:form.object name="language" label="Language">
                <flux:field.input name="languagename" label="Language Visible Name"/>
                <flux:field.select name="language" label="System Language" items="{
                           0:{0:'English',1:'&L=1'},
                           1:{0:'German',1:'&L=2'}
                           }" />
                <flux:field.input name="url" label="URL">
                    <flux:wizard.link/>
                </flux:field.input>
            </flux:form.object>
        </flux:form.section>
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Preview">
        Preview
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Main">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <ul  class="languages">
            <f:for each="{languages}" as="langele"> 
                <li><v:link.typolink configuration="{parameter: langele.language.url, additionalParams: langele.language.language}">{langele.language.languagename} {langele.language.language}</v:link.typolink></li>
            </f:for>
        </ul>
    </f:section>
```

This works but I have 2 problems I can't solve yet:

**1. additionalParams**

Right now the select items have the values like  `&L=1`. I had to do it this way cause I was not able to add the `&L=` directly in the typolink configuration. What I would like to have is something like that:

```
<v:link.typolink configuration="{parameter: langele.language.url, additionalParams: '&L='langele.language.language}">
```

With this I could have just the ID in the select-items.
Is this possible and if so, how?

**2. select items Query**

The documentation says it is possible to fill the items of the `flux:field.select` with a query. But I can not find any example. What I would like to have is all the languages configured in typo3 in this select-box.
Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something correction in fluxform:

```
<flux:field.select name="language" label="System Language" 
items="{1:'English',2:'German'}" />
```

you can use fluid typolink instead of vhs viewhelper

```
<f:for each="{languages}" as="langele"> 
     <li><f:link.typolink parameter="{langele.language.url}" additionalParams="&L={langele.language.language}">{langele.language.languagename} {langele.language.language}</f:link.typolink></li>
</f:for>
```

But as per your need, I suggest to you use fluid page link:

```
<f:for each="{languages}" as="langele">
    <li><f:link.page pageUid="{langele.language.url}" additionalParams="{L:'{langele.language.language}'}">{langele.language.languagename} {langele.language.language}</f:link.page></li>
</f:for>
```

Comment: thanks works nice. To the fluxform I guess when I use it this way (which is shorter and nicer) I cant use strings as keyvalue? Also do you have an idea how to use the configured languages in `flux:field.select`?

Comment: strings as keyvalue - did you mean "English" and "German"? and your question I didn't understand "Also do you have an idea how to use the configured languages in flux:field.select?"

Comment: I mean something like 'de':'German'. And the my question is the second question `2. select items Query` in the original thread. Basicly I want to use the languages configured in typo3 in this select-field.

Comment: for 'de' or 'en' then you must use realurl extension or others for pretty urls, in realurl configuration file you can set "preVars" like '1' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array (
     'en' => '1',
     'de' => '2'
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),

Comment: about you second question: you have created custom element as per your need so either you can use that element as global or for particular page I mean you can insert element in one page and use it for all Or you have to insert for all page